# WordPress - How to get CSS classes of menu items with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add an additional menu item to my navigation via my **functions.php**

The code below works, but how can I add the CSS classes which are used in the navigation to the li element automatically without writing each class manually in the below stated function= There must be something like `get_classes_for_li_elements()` - does someone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_home_items', 'add_itemcart_to_menu' , 10, 2 ); 

    function add_itemcart_to_menu( $items, $args ) {
            $menu_item_li = '<li><a href="">My Item</a></li>';

        return $items . $menu_item_li;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, do you want to attach to your li element a list of class found on another element ? Look for `element.classList` or `element.className`

Comment: @cyrbil - i am adding an additional element to my navigation but this is just added with <li> - all other items in $items which are returned to the navigation have several classes which they get from wordpress. I want to attach those classes to my li element as well

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like 
    $menu_item_li = 'My Item';

or asign a class used by your theme

Comment: $menu_item_li = '<li class="globalclass"><a href="">My Item</a></li>'; sorry